# Gson - Read a value with two different keys

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gson, android-json

In my Android project I have two types of response where both **response are identical except two keys**.

Response 1

```
{"fullName":"William Sherlock Scott Holmes","address":"221B Baker Street, London, England, UK","downloads":642,"rating":3,"repos":["https://link1","https://link2","https://link3"]}
```

Response 2

```
{"name":"Sherlock","city":"London","downloads":642,"rating":3,"repos":["https://link1","https://link2","https://link3"]}
```

If you see the responses only two key names are changing  **fullName/name** and **address/city**

I don't want to create one more pojo for other response. My question is: is it possible to use only one Pojo to read both responses?

```
public class AccountInfo {
    private String name;
    private String city;
    //other objects

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    //other setters and getters
}
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Make those extra fields getter and setter, if the getter field is empty it won't create any problem. Try this and let me know if I can help you with anything else

Comment: @Rakshit thanks. check Doug Stevenson answer..

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can annotate the members to accept values from two different json names using the [@SerializedName](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation:

```
@SerializedName(value = "name", alternate = {"fullName"})
private String name;
@SerializedName(value = "city", alternate = {"address"})
private String city;
```

Either named element can then be placed into the members that are annotated like this.

**UPDATED :** 
`@SerializedName` alternate names when deserializing is added in **[Version 2.4](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)**

Comment: getting    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can totally use one POJO class for deserializing both responses. Your POJO class will contain keys from both responses.

```
public class Response {


private String name;
private String city;
private String fullName;
private String address;
private Integer downloads;
private Integer rating;
private List<String> repos ;

}
```

But when using the Response class, be careful that for **first response**, the **name** and **city** will be **null**, and for the **second one**, the **address** and **fullname**.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can do that in a single POJO. Try this:

```
public class POJO {

@SerializedName("name")
public String name;

@SerializedName("city")
public String city;

@SerializedName("fullName")
public String fullName;

@SerializedName("address")
public String address;

@SerializedName("downloads")
public Integer downloads;

@SerializedName("rating")
public Integer rating;

@SerializedName("repos")
public List<String> repos = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

While parsing you have to check values for **null**. For eg -

While Parsing Response 1: **name** and **city** variables will be null

While Parsing Response 2: **fullname** and **address** will be null

Note : Try checking values for null before using else you'll get **nullpointerexception**

Comment: Thanks very much... @Doug Stevenson answer is more use full because I don't have to check for `null`.

Comment: Bad approach for doing this

Answer (score 0):

Define all possible fields in your POJO Class like

```
    public class AccountInfo {
      private String name;
      private String city;
      private String fullname;
      private String address;
    }
```

While performing operation check for null in those feilds

Comment: well. thanks for the answer... But didn't you check that other answers are same what you answered...